# How to construct an intersect formula in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I currently have a column of data with numbers. I want to create a second column which returns TRUE when a set of multiple conditions are TRUE. This column should return FALSE when one or more conditions are FALSE. The conditions are the following:

- The number is negative (<= 0)
- The number in this list is the closest to zero
- The number in this list is not #N/A

The big trouble I'm having is because of these #N/A's in my dataset. I can't get my formula to ignore it. This is the current formula I use in column B, but for some reason I can't get this to work:

`=IF(AND(A1<=0;A1=MAX(IF(NOT(IFNA($A$1:$A$300;TRUE));TRUE;FALSE)));TRUE;FALSE)`

I suppose something's wrong in my interpretation of the `IF(NOT(IFNA(...)) part`.
Sorry if it's obvious, but can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want the number to be the closest negative number to zero? If your numbers were -3,-2,-1,0.1,0.2,0.3 then -1 would be the closest negative number to zero, but 0.1 would be the closest number to zero. Can zero itself be included (because your first condition is <=0) ? Ideally, include some example data with expected results.

Comment: To confirm, yes, I only want to return "TRUE" with the closest _negative_ number to zero. Upvoting your answer below, this was exactly what I was looking for! Lifesaver!

Answer (score 2):

I would use aggregate because there is an option to exclude NA's:

```
=IF(ISNA(A1),FALSE,A1=AGGREGATE(14,6,A$1:A$10/(A$1:A$10<0),1))
```

[image]

(this is assuming the number should be equal to the nearest negative number to zero, in other words the highest negative number. In this case you don't need a separate test for the number being negative)

Comment: As stated above, this was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!!

Comment: That's good! I did work out a formula for the case where you wanted to compare the number to the positive or negative number closest to zero, but it was a lot longer and more messy.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the **array formula**:

```
=IF(ISNA(A1),FALSE,IF(A1>0,FALSE,IF(A1=MAX(IF(A:A<0,A:A)),TRUE,FALSE)))
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

[image]